# Heroku Search to EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, heroku, amazon-ec2

I am looking into solutions for search in my Ruby on Rails app hosted on Heroku and Amazon RDS.

I have been looking into Flying Sphinx, WebSolr and most recently Bonsai Search.  These look good but either quite expensive, (I have a table with 8 millions rows) or not ideal solutions for what I want.

I was wondering if it was possible to setup Solr, or Elastic Search on my own EC2 box and use the search service from my Heroku application, without the need of an Addon? If so, are there any resources available to explain how you can implement this?

Comment: How did you get on with this? I'm looking to do the same.

Comment: Yep working without any issues.  I decided to go with using Sunspot, and setup a Solr server in the EC2 cloud.   Then it was as simple as pointing the Sunspot config to the external search server.  It took a few config changes in Solr to get it working with Sunpot, but it was pretty straight forward.

Comment: Cool, sounds good. What size EC2 instance did you go with? For my site, it's a very small data set in comparison to yours, only around 5k rows that i'll ever want to index. Do you think an EC2 micro will suffice?

Comment: Yep small EC2 would be perfect I reckon.  I would say it would depend more on the number of queries you going to be doing rather than the size of the data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can - you can build up any service you like externally, and connect to it from your own Heroku application.

For more information on setting things up, Google is probably your friend.